# Discord bot help (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code Im working on (looking for a working version, full code at bottom):

```
def a(number):
  while number > 0:
    @client.event
    async def send_message(): 
        channel.send("j")
        number = number - 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

trying to get the bot to spam j. Orignlly i had:

```
def a(number):
  while number > 0:
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message): 
        await message.channel.send("j")
        number = number - 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

But it won't start spamming j until another command is typed. Example (in discord)
!spam-j
(nothing happens)
!helloworld (just a test command has nothing to do with the j spam code)
Bot:(starts spamming j)
I think this is because of the await part but I don't know how to get rid of it.

```
import discord
import os
import time
import threading

client = discord.Client()
def b():
  while True:
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        message.channel.send("j")
        if message.content.startswith('!stop'):
          a(0)
          print("did")
        
def a(number):
  while number > 0:
    @client.event
    async def send_message(): 
        channel.send("j")
        number = number - 1
        time.sleep(2)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!helloworld'):
        await message.channel.send('working!')
    
    if message.content.startswith('!spam-jprep'):
      await message.channel.send("ready")
      threading.Thread(target=a(10)).start()
      #threading.Thread(target=b).start()  

        #while x > 0:
          #if message.content.startswith('!stop'):
           # x = 0
           # print ("seen")
       

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what is it your trying to make here. If you are trying to make a simple command that just spams a message it can easily be done with,

```
@client.command()
async def spam(ctx):
    while True:
        await ctx.send("j")
```

With this, you should also add sleep events `await asyncio.sleep(10)` so it doesn't get rate limited. But this is a simple example of using a `while True`.

This is a better example when you can control it and it would simply set the spam variable to `True`, which would set the while true loop to spam your letter or message.

```
spam_j = True

@client.command()
async def spam(ctx):
    global spam_j
    spam_j= True

    while true:
        if not spam_j:
            break

        await ctx.send("j")

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    global spam_j
    spam_j= False
    await ctx.send('Stopped spamming')
```